# How to: Database Model in Visio 2013

Tags: database, sql-server, microsoft-visio-2013

I am unable to find the "Database Model" in Visio 2013 and upon linking an existing database to Visio, there is no option to Reverse Engineer. Where do I find this functionality?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Reverse Engineering in Visio 2013 has been removed, according to the Visio blog:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2012/10/17/uml-and-database-diagrams-in-the-new-visio/

> Deprecations
>
> The new software and database diagramming capabilities in Visio
>   represent a departure from the capabilities of previous versions. We
>   place a strong emphasis on diagramming and sharing instead of rigorous
>   modeling. Specifically, there is no ability to generate a diagram from
>   existing code or a database definition. Also - just like in recent
>   releases - there is no ability to go from diagram to code or database.
>   Existing UML and Database diagrams can be opened in the new Visio, but
>   they are effectively frozen for editing since the previous feature set
>   has been removed. The behavior of existing diagrams is equivalent to
>   the experience you get today when opening them in Visio 2010 Standard.

There are alternatives:

- Use Visio 2010 instead. Note: If linking to SQL Server 2012, follow [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/29327) suggestion.
- Visual Studio using the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907.aspx)<sup>[1](http://superuser.com/questions/578090/how-to-database-model-in-visio-2013#comment707181_578091)</sup>: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878

Comment: You already know the answer, but I believe the VS Team took this functionality and put it into Entity Framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907.aspx

Comment: You might want to expand your answer by explaining what the user can do instead since this functionality has been removed. What are the remaining options, if any?

Comment: I don't see how EF is anywhere a replacement for the Visio functionality. In Visio you were presented with a way to make attractive versions of the diagram that could be used for printed materials/etc. EF pretty much does what the "Data Diagram" in SQL Server Management Studio does.

Comment: not really, if you use database diagram in SMSS it doesn't automatically add relationships.

Answer (score 0):

A typical Microsoft move...take something that works, that the user community finds useful and remove it, in hopes of sticking it into another application to force that community to by another application for the one feature.  It's cheaper to switch to a non MS application and avoid the hassle.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1149884)