# How do you create database diagrams in Visio 2013?

Tags: database, microsoft-visio-2013

I'm not trying to [reverse engineer](https://superuser.com/q/578090/302) a database, simply trying to create a database diagram from scratch in Visio 2013 (Standard edition).

If I choose the "Crow's Foot Database Notation.vstx" template (as in the default install), it doesn't appear to have any shapes nor a document stencil, so what use is it? I gather from watching screencasts that there *should* be shapes there? Is there anything additional I need to install to get this to work?

Comment: @Devid per the question "Visio 2013 (Standard edition)"

Comment: I thing stencils are only available in Visio Professional.

Comment: I have run into the same issue. It seems more than a bit odd that Visio 2013 Standard would provide all of the document templates for database and UML diagrams when you can't get the stencils.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That feature has been removed in Visio 2013.

The following is from the [MS Office Blog](http://blogs.office.com/b/visio/archive/2012/10/17/uml-and-database-diagrams-in-the-new-visio.aspx):

> Existing UML and Database diagrams can be opened in the new Visio, but they are effectively frozen for editing since the previous feature set has been removed. The behavior of existing diagrams is equivalent to the experience you get today when opening them in Visio 2010 Standard.

Comment: I'm talking about the database diagrams that come with Visio 2013; Per the link in my question, I was aware that the database diagramming from previous versions won't work as intended.